# Is Sonarqube 4.5.x supported on SQL 12?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sonarqube

I have searched SonarQube site and here, but the support page does not state which versions are supported on MS SQL Server 12.  Not sure if it's all versions of just the latest.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements

It states that it supports it, but it doesn't state which versions are supported on MS SQL Server 2012.

We are upgrading from 4.4 to 4.5.4 LTS and we want to know if 4.4 and 4.5.4 supports MS SQL Server 2012?  Our SQL team is planning upgrades and I don't want to allow them to upgrade too soon.

Comment: NVM, I found the info I needed.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MsSQL 2012 is supported, it's written in the link you've provided in your question (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements).